Safe Assignment Operator in JavaScript, a myth or reality?
I've been going through Medium to get some updates about programming. A couple of articles confused me that were related to "Safe Assignment Operator":
async function getData() {
    const [networkError, res] ?= await fetch('https://api.backend.com/resource/1')
    
    if(networkError) console.error(networkError)
    const [parseError, data] ?= await res.json()

    if(parseError) console.error(parseError)
    return data
            
}

I tried finding the official documentation on MDN,  but nothing found. I also tried on console but no luck.
Is this a myth or isn't the MDN site updated?
Here is the article that build up the confusion. Medium Article

It's just a proposal. I believe the ?= operator syntax has already been rejected, though. Remember: Medium articles are neither rare nor well done.

You can safely disregard the articles by that author. They presented the safe assignment operator as something that's right around the corner when...it might be years to be adopted. Most likely it will not even be what's in the proposal right now. It seems to be an article written for the sake of views. I started reading this other article of theirs and it started with such nonsense, that I figured nothing can really redeem it. I've not checked the other articles. I don't think it's worth it.

Also, just in general, take basically anything on Medium with a very big helping of salt. Anybody can publish articles there. And that's exactly what happens - just anybody does. Note that there are good authors and articles, too. I've just learned that's not what one should expect when opening an unknown article. Most are either missing details or just straight up wrong.

There is a proposal for a safe assignment operator (?=). The aim is to simplify error handling without needing try/catch but using:
const [error, result] ?= doWork();

as opposed to:
try {
  const result = doWork();
} catch (error) {

}

However, this is still a very early proposal that does not even show up on the proposal track for ECMAScript. This is typically a six stage process with stage zero being just marked as there but not yet considered. The proposal is not at stage zero yet.
Moreover, the earliness of the proposal is evident by looking at its README which currently says on top:

Caution
This proposal will change to try-expressions as its a more idiomatic apporach to this problem. Read more on #4 and #5.
Help on its rewriting is needed :)

So, it can change further before even entering the proposal track from TC39.
